# How to run nunit tests iteratively

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, execution

I use nUnit framework to run tests and I was wondering if there was a way to run my tests more than once. One after the other. I have sporadical tests, and I would use this to monitor how many times they fail. For example I'd start that before I go to sleep and in the morning I could see the results. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Well, maybe I could write a script that executes the test repeatedly. The point is I would like to see the results of all execution.

Comment: You could probably use a continuous integration tool like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: What is it you really want to accomplish?  If your tests are deterministic, running them multiple times does not accomplish anything more than the initial test run does.  If they're non-deterministic, they need to be re-written.  If you simply want to run them nightly, then you want a CI tool as per Jeff's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've hacked it like this before:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest([Range(0, 10)] int iteration)
{
...
}
```

[NUnit Range Attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=range&r=2.5)